# Using externalmedia library of openmodelica I want to get CO2 thermal conductivity data

Tags: model, simulation, modelica, openmodelica, dymola

I am using openmodelica to model a gas cooler where one fluid is CO2 and I want to get the value of its thermal conductivity at specified temperature and pressure. I am using the externalmedia library. Want to get this property value from Coolprop.

I tried to get the values writing Real k=ExternalMedia.Example.CO2COOLCoolProp.thermalConductivity(P,T); here, P, T are the pressure and temperature values mentioned before. When I do this it keeps giving me error messages. One error message says: No matching function found for ExternalMedia.Examples.CO2CoolProp.thermalConductivity(/*Real*/ P, /*Real*/ tw).
Candidates are:
ExternalMedia.Examples.CO2CoolProp.thermalConductivity(ExternalMedia.Examples.CO2CoolProp.ThermodynamicState state) => Real